# Allocated unallocated space to Ubuntu using GParted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have unallocated space on my disk that I want to allocate to Ubuntu (I also have Windows installed on my computer). I have been trying to use GParted to do that. I have the following screen:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yboEc.png)

Even though I have unallocated space, when I click on /dev/sda5 to resize/move, it shows 0 free space preceding, and does not allow me to resize. How can I reconfigure my partitions so I can use the unallocated space within my Ubuntu OS? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try booting into a live session (from dvd or USB) and then resize?

Comment: as @hmayag implied - you shouldn't (*hence gparted didn't offer it*) resize a *ext4* partition when in use; and your graphic shows it mounted as /.  by booting a 'live' session (including your Ubuntu install media) it won't be in use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda5 left
- **resize** sda5 right